# Get value from the multiple dropdown menu and concatenate them as one in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

in the following code i want to extract the value of book,chapter and ver and concatenate from the each drop down menu.So, please do help me on where should I implement the concatenation of three string and get them as one value. For an example : if book= john, chapter=3, and ver=16, I should be able to get "john 3:16".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ExpandedListAnimationWidget.dart';
import 'Scrollbar.dart';
class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropDownState createState() => _DropDownState();
}
List<String> _book = [
  'Genesis',
  'Exodus',
  'Leviticus',
  'Numbers',
  'Deuteronomy',
  'Joshua',
  'Judges',
  'Ruth',
  '1 Samuel',
  '2 Samuel',
  '1 Kings',
  '2 Kings',
  '1 Chronicles',
  '2 Chronicles',
  'Ezra',
  'Nehemiah',
  'Esther',
  'Job',
  'Psalms',
  'Proverbs',
  'Ecclesiastes',
  'Song of Solomon',
  'Isaiah',
  'Jeremiah',
  'Lamentations',
  'Ezekiel',
  'Daniel',
  'Hosea',
  'Joel',
  'Amos',
  'Obadiah',
  'Jonah',
  'Micah',
  'Nahum',
  'Habakkuk',
  'Zephaniah',
  'Haggai',
  'Zechariah',
  'Malachi',
  'Matthew',
  'Mark',
  'Luke',
  'John',
  'Acts',
  'Romans',
  '1 Corinthians',
  '2 Corinthians',
  'Galatians',
  'Ephesians',
  'Philippians',
  'Colossians',
  '1 Thessalonians',
  '2 Thessalonians',
  '1 Timothy',
  '2 Timothy',
  'Titus',
  'Philemon',
  'Hebrew',
  'James',
  '1 Peter',
  '2 Peter',
  '1 John',
  '2 John',
  '3 John',
  'Jude',
  'Revelation'
];
List<String> _chapter = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
  '11',
  '12',
  '13',
  '14',
  '15',
  '16',
  '17',
  '18',
  '19',
  '20',
  '21',
  '22',
  '23',
  '24',
  '25',
  '26',
  '27',
  '28',
  '29',
  '30',
  '31',
  '32',
  '33',
  '34',
  '35',
  '36',
  '37',
  '38',
  '39',
  '40',
  '41',
  '42',
  '43',
  '44',
  '45',
  '46',
  '47',
  '48',
  '49',
  '50',
  '51',
  '52',
  '53',
  '54',
  '55',
  '56',
  '57',
  '58',
  '59',
  '60',
  '61',
  '62',
  '63',
  '64',
  '65',
  '66',
  '67',
  '68',
  '69',
  '70',
  '71',
  '72',
  '73',
  '74',
  '75',
  '76',
  '77',
  '78',
  '79',
  '80',
  '81',
  '82',
  '83',
  '84',
  '85',
  '86',
  '87',
  '88',
  '89',
  '90',
  '91',
  '92',
  '93',
  '94',
  '95',
  '96',
  '97',
  '98',
  '99',
  '100',
  '101',
  '102',
  '103',
  '104',
  '105',
  '106',
  '107',
  '108',
  '109',
  '110',
  '111',
  '112',
  '113',
  '114',
  '115',
  '116',
  '117',
  '118',
  '119',
  '120',
  '121',
  '122',
  '123',
  '124',
  '125',
  '126',
  '127',
  '128',
  '129',
  '130',
  '131',
  '132',
  '133',
  '134',
  '135',
  '136',
  '137',
  '138',
  '139',
  '140',
  '141',
  '142',
  '143',
  '144',
  '145',
  '146',
  '147',
  '148',
  '149',
  '150'
];
List<String> _verse = [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
  '11',
  '12',
  '13',
  '14',
  '15',
  '16',
  '17',
  '18',
  '19',
  '20',
  '21',
  '22',
  '23',
  '24',
  '25',
  '26',
  '27',
  '28',
  '29',
  '30',
  '31',
  '32',
  '33',
  '34',
  '35',
  '36',
  '37',
  '38',
  '39',
  '40',
  '41',
  '42',
  '43',
  '44',
  '45',
  '46',
  '47',
  '48',
  '49',
  '50',
  '51',
  '52',
  '53',
  '54',
  '55',
  '56',
  '57',
  '58',
  '59',
  '60',
  '61',
  '62',
  '63',
  '64',
  '65',
  '66',
  '67',
  '68',
  '69',
  '70',
  '71',
  '72',
  '73',
  '74',
  '75',
  '76',
  '77',
  '78',
  '79',
  '80',
  '81',
  '82',
  '83',
  '84',
  '85',
  '86',
  '87',
  '88',
  '89',
  '90',
  '91',
  '92',
  '93',
  '94',
  '95',
  '96',
  '97',
  '98',
  '99',
  '100',
  '101',
  '102',
  '103',
  '104',
  '105',
  '106',
  '107',
  '108',
  '109',
  '110',
  '111',
  '112',
  '113',
  '114',
  '115',
  '116',
  '117',
  '118',
  '119',
  '120',
  '121',
  '122',
  '123',
  '124',
  '125',
  '126',
  '127',
  '128',
  '129',
  '130',
  '131',
  '132',
  '133',
  '134',
  '135',
  '136',
  '137',
  '138',
  '139',
  '140',
  '141',
  '142',
  '143',
  '144',
  '145',
  '146',
  '147',
  '148',
  '149',
  '150'
];
class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  bool isStrechedDropDown = false;
  String book;
  String ver;
  String chapter;
  int bookValue;
  int chapterValue;
  int verseValue;
  String title = 'Select Book';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Retrieve Bible Verse ",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffbbbbbb)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(27))),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color(0xffbbbbbb),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                minHeight: 30,
                                minWidth: double.infinity,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                      child: Text(
                                        title,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isStrechedDropDown =
                                              !isStrechedDropDown;
                                          book;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(isStrechedDropDown
                                          ? Icons.arrow_upward
                                          : Icons.arrow_downward))
                                ],
                              )),
                          ExpandedSection(
                            expand: isStrechedDropDown,
                            height: 30,
                            child: MyScrollbar(
                              builder: (context, scrollController1) =>
                                  ListView.builder(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                      controller: scrollController1,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: _book.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return RadioListTile(
                                            title: Text(_book.elementAt(index)),
                                            value: index,
                                            groupValue: bookValue,
                                            onChanged: (val) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                bookValue = val;
                                                book = _book.elementAt(index);
                                                print(book);
                                              });
                                            });
                                      }),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //Text("Please Select Chapter"),
                          Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color(0xffbbbbbb),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                minHeight: 30,
                                minWidth: double.infinity,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                      child: Text("Select Chapter"),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isStrechedDropDown =
                                              !isStrechedDropDown;
                                          chapter;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(isStrechedDropDown
                                          ? Icons.arrow_upward
                                          : Icons.arrow_downward))
                                ],
                              )),
                          ExpandedSection(
                            expand: isStrechedDropDown,
                            height: 30,
                            child: MyScrollbar(
                              builder: (context, scrollController2) =>
                                  ListView.builder(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                      controller: scrollController2,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: _chapter.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return RadioListTile(
                                            title:
                                                Text(_chapter.elementAt(index)),
                                            value: index,
                                            groupValue: chapterValue,
                                            onChanged: (chap) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                chapterValue = chap;
                                                chapter =
                                                    _chapter.elementAt(index);
                                                print(chapter);
                                              });
                                            });
                                      }),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              height: 40,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color(0xffbbbbbb),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25))),
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                minHeight: 30,
                                minWidth: double.infinity,
                              ),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                                      child: Text("Select Verse"),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isStrechedDropDown =
                                              !isStrechedDropDown;
                                          ver;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(isStrechedDropDown
                                          ? Icons.arrow_upward
                                          : Icons.arrow_downward))
                                ],
                              )),
                          ExpandedSection(
                            expand: isStrechedDropDown,
                            height: 30,
                            child: MyScrollbar(
                              builder: (context, scrollController3) =>
                                  ListView.builder(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                      controller: scrollController3,
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: _verse.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        return RadioListTile(
                                            title:
                                                Text(_verse.elementAt(index)),
                                            value: index,
                                            groupValue: verseValue,
                                            onChanged: (verse) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                verseValue = verse;
                                                ver = _verse.elementAt(index);
                                                print(ver);
                                              });
                                            });
                                      }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with this

```
"$book $chapter:$verse"
```

Comment: Thanks  for the reply but i am getting following error:  his expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Comment: where you call this? please share your code

Comment: setState(() {
                                                verseValue = verse;
                                                ver = _verse.elementAt(index);
                                                print(ver);
                                              });
                                            });
                                      }),
                            ),
                          ),

                            print("$book $chapter:$ver ")

Comment: you called it out side of setState; you called it in your setstate, otherwise you can show your data in the text `Text("$book $chapter:$verse")`

Comment: in place of `print("$book $chapter:$ver ")` you paste `Text("$book $chapter:$verse")`

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. what if i have to store the value in order to pass it to the URL or any other class.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Just `book+" "+chapter+":"+verse` should do it. It's elementary string concatenation.